# 400ms gap between html file and DOMcontentloaded?

Tags: http, google-chrome, express, google-chrome-devtools

Why is it a gap (almost 400ms) between when the html-file has been downloaded and the DOMcontentloaded event?

What is the browser doing? :S

[image]

Comment: Could you add your HTML? It looks like it wouldn't be very large (I'm guessing it's basically just the script and link elements in the head, but I wanted to be sure)

Comment: Yea its just the link elements and a h1 tag

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that though you reference the jquery Source map, that you aren't including any JavaScript? Or is that being filtered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Disconnect Chrome-plugin. It loads a jquery source map which takes 300ms...
After some testing I also noticed that addblocker makes a 100ms gap

Answer (score 1):

The delay could possibly be node.js (server side) related.  Here is my timeline on my Macbook pro running Tomcat (you see the delay I assume parsing, but not nearly as long):

[image: Timeline]

With the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Loaded</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer really helped! But I think I found what really caused it. It was the Disconnect-chromeplugin that loads the source map. If I remove the plugin I save 300ms(!).
I still get the gap but its about as long as yours. Maybe it has something to do with my node server, but now its not a big deal.
Thank you very much for your time! :)
(hmm should I create a new answer and mark it as the correct one or yours?)

Comment: That is an interesting side effect of the `Disconnect-chromeplugin`, maybe you could report it as an issue.